# difference between calling create and new() in ruby with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Suppose I have a class `Try`. Then I am trying to create its object to use it in one of the examples in rspec file.

I tried writing `let(:obj){obj = Try.new()}` and then accessing it in the example but it gave error. However when I wrote `llet(:obj){obj = Try.create}`, I could use the `obj` and call its functions without any error.

What is difference when I write as `Try.create` and `Try.new()` in rspec file?

Comment: Depends entirely on what the Try class is. Not all classes have a create method for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) documentation:

```
create(attributes = nil) {|object| ...}
```

Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

```
new(attributes = nil) {|self if block_given?| ...}
```

New objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction parameter) or pre-set with attributes but not yet saved (pass a hash with key names matching the associated table column names). In both instances, valid attribute keys are determined by the column names of the associated table — hence you can‘t have attributes that aren‘t part of the table columns.
So create instantiates the new object, validates it, and then saves it to the database. And new only creates the local object but does not attempt to validate or save it to the DB.